# How to parse path-parameter with webapp2

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, webapp2, path-parameter

I am coming from a Java REST background to `Python` on `Google App Engine's`. I need some help using `webapp2` with path-parameters. Below is an example of how Java would read a request. Will someone please translate the code into how python would read it with `webapp2`?

```
// URL: my_dogs/user_id/{user_id}/dog_name/{a_name}/breed/{breed}/{weight}

@Path("my_dogs/user_id/{user_id}/dog_name/{a_name}/breed/{breed}/{weight}")
public Response getMyDog(
    @PathParam("user_id") Integer id,
    @PathParam("a_name") String name,
    @PathParam("breed") String breed,
    @PathParam("weight") String weight
){

//the variables are: id, name, breed, weight.
///use them somehow

}
```

I have already gone over the examples on google ( https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/usingwebapp ). But I don't know how to extend the simple

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                           ('/sign', Guestbook)],
                          debug=True)
```

Comment: How do I change the following to look like mine? `webapp2.Route(r'/products', handler='handlers.ProductsHandler', name='products-list', methods=['GET'])`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at URI routing in webapp2. Here you can match / route an URI and get the arguments. These keyword arguments are passed to your handler : http://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/routing.html#the-url-template

Here is a helloworld example with one argument {action} :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import webapp2

class ActionPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self, action):

        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'        
        self.response.out.write('Action, ' + action)

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):

        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('Hello, webapp2 World!')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
        webapp2.Route(r'/<action:(start|failed)>', handler=ActionPage),
        webapp2.Route(r'/', handler=MainPage),                    
], debug=True)
```

And your app.yaml:

```
application: helloworld
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: false

handlers:
- url: (.*)
  script: helloworld.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
```

This works fine in the SDK when I try

```
http://localhost:8080/start   # result: Action, start
or
http://localhost:8080         # result: Hello, webapp2 World!
```

Comment: I read that link before posting. For some reason I am not getting it. So I figure having someone parse my own example for me would help.

Comment: How would I modify this? `webapp2.Route(r'/products', handler='handlers.ProductsHandler', name='products-list', methods=['GET'])`

Comment: I have given you a piece of my own code, so I do not make a mistake. Now you can figure out how to handle your own path with keyword arguments.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I try your path with the helloworld example on the google site. Basically the parameters do nothing. Still the path should work, but it does not work. The link to the example: `https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/helloworld`.

Comment: of course I change to `handler=helloworld.MainPage`; then I try a few other different things: Nothing.

Comment: I habe added the helloworld example and included the app.yaml